# PHP Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I had this error twice and spent almost 30 minutes to debug it each time. I Hope it will help somebody because all I've found on the internet is solution for turning off xDebug.

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I have accidentally injected two classes into each other.

```
class Foo(Bar $bar){}

class Bar(Foo $foo){}


$bar = new Bar(new Foo(new bar(new Foo(...))));
```

The reason why didn't saw that is because of Laravel IOC. So synax for instantiating a class would be something like:

```
$bar = new Bar(Foo $foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is caused by default xdebug.max_nesting_level which is 100.

By adding the line below to bootstrap/autoload.php in Laravel 5.1

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 120);

.........

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
```

This answered helped me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30839127/3524046

Answer (score -1):

Here the issue in my case.

I have a service class which is librarie in codeigniter. Having a a function inside like this.

```
class PaymentService {

    private $CI;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->CI =& get_instance();

    }

    public function procss(){
        // lots of Ci referencing here ...
    }
```

my controller as followed:

```
$this->load->library('PaymentService');
$this->process_(); // see I got his wrong instead it should be like below

$this->Payment_service->process(); //the library class name
```

Then I was keeping getting the exceed error message. But I do disable XDebug but non helped. Any way please check you class name or your code for proper function calling.

Comment: This sounds rather like a "me too" comment than an actual answer to the question.