# Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting after upgrading to Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, homestead

I'm getting this error message in my Laravel application after I upgraded to Laravel 5.1.

```
FatalErrorException in Dispatcher.php line 200:
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

[image]

This issue occurs on some URLs of my app. I have done dozens of `composer update` but issue still persist. Any suggestion at all will be appreciated

Comment: You can increase the limit in php.ini, but this is likely a logic error - some function is either calling itself or a loop isn't being properly closed.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I think a function is calling itself over and over. I don't wish to increase limit in php.ini, will like to find and fix it

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Issue is caused by default `xdebug.max_nesting_level` which is 100.

The workaround for now is to increase `xdebug.max_nesting_level` to a certain level say 200 or 300 or 400

I fixed mine by increasing xdebug.max_nesting_level to 120, by adding the line below to `bootstrap/autoload.php` in Laravel 5.1

`ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 120);`

.........

`define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));`

Answer (score 10):

The problem is created because of 1 PHP extension in Apache- [php_xdebug](https://xdebug.org/)

So, the solution is-

1. Disable the extension
2. Increase the  nesting level of the extension
3. Increasing `max_nesting_level` in laravel

### In detail

**Option 1-**

To disable it, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754826/how-to-disable-xdebug).

If you are using [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), then you can easily do it by going to **php.ini**-
[image]

And then commit this-

```
zend_extension = "c:/WAMP/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"
```

- Path should be different from PC to PC
- Adding an # before the line is a comment

**Option 2-**

You can increase the limit by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293775/increasing-nesting-functions-calls-limit) way.

If you are using [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), then you can easily do it by going to **php.ini**-

And after `zend_extension = "c:/WAMP/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"`, there should be something like this-

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/WAMP/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

Then, just add 1 line there-

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=500
```

**Option 3-**

You can also set this configuration in Laravel [**autoload.php**](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/bootstrap/autoload.php) file.

You can simply add this line in the file (anywhere in the file)-

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 500);
```

And you will be done :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to xdebug extension is enabled, 
to fix this either you have to disable xdebug extension or edit php.ini file and  change **xdebug.max_nesting_level** to 200 ( as by default this parameter is not included in php.ini and have to add it )

like :

**xdebug.max_nesting_level=200**