# Issue with middleware "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I had a controller, lets call it DummyController, that performs CRUD operations in the root of controllers folder. I have moved dummy controller into a different directory, a level higher, so our DummyController is now in folder named 'r'.

Due to that I have updated the edit form, which is used with dummy controller:

```
{!! Form::model($message, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['r\DummyController@update', $message->id]]) !!}
```

And now it's broken. I have tried playing around with controller and narrowed the issue down to middleware that I use in Dummy Controller. I have 'auth' middleware and my own 'role' middleware:

```
if (Auth::user()->role_id != config('Roles.admin')) {
            return redirect('/');
        }
```

If I remove one middleware everything starts working, I cant have both running, which is strange because before it worked fine.

Comment: Please post the full text of the error message ([edit] it into the body of the question). There may be clues in it that are useful to someone helping you.

Comment: This error could be caused by several thing. This will be able to resolve it: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803342/maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-aborting-after-upgrading-to-lar