# How to fix laravel 5.2 this error "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!"?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to reset password from laravel auto generated login/register authentication module. When i click on reset button it give me this error 
`FatalErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 344:
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`

I searched about it and find an accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656089/solution-for-fatal-error-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-abor), but this answer does not work on my side i have followed the instruction. Can any one guide me it is laravel error or wamp ? and how can fix it. I would like to appreciate.

Comment: You must have initialised a class A in the constructor of class B, and class A must be initialising class B, and so it stucks in forever loop
Can you share your code so that i can exactly see whats going on.

Comment: @AmmarAjmal I just install laravel 5.2 authentication module, there is not additional code.

Comment: I got this error right now. any solutions yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting after upgrading to Laravel 5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803342/maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-aborting-after-upgrading-to-lar)

Comment: In my case, it is caused right where I declare, in my Model class, the `protected $with = ['relationship1', 'relationship2'];` in Laravel 5.6

Comment: @Pathros are you facing same problem in 5.6?

Comment: @AyazShah. Yes. I have just discovered why this is happening: I got this one-to-many relationship. That is to say, in model `Research` I have a list. And in `Subject` model, I have another list of subjects that belong to a specific register of Research. Well, declaring `protected $with = ['relationships'];` on both sides are causing this `Maximum function nesting level` error. So i have to leave just one `$with`, in one of these two models, and the error goes away.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Issue is caused by default xdebug.max_nesting_level which is 100.

The workaround for now is to increase xdebug.max_nesting_level to a certain level say 200 or 300 or 400.

I fixed mine by increasing xdebug.max_nesting_level to 120, by adding the line below to `bootstrap/autoload.php` in the Laravel 5.1

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 120);
```

............

```
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
```

Comment: Worked for me @DucaBgd

Answer (score 23):

This usually happens because you are loading the relations from the two models at once by something like `$with` property.

Let's say a `Category` hasMany `Product` and a `Product` belongsTo a `Category`.

If in both models you load the relations by default like this:
in `Product` model `$with=['category']`, in `Category` model `$with=['products']`

This would result this infinite nesting. So, to solve this load the relations whenever wanted only.

Also this could happen with GlobalScopes and the idea is similar to `$with` property.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This solve the root cause.

Comment: This was my issue as well. This should definitely be higher. You got my upvote.

Comment: Thanks for that ! Solved my issue too :)

Comment: Thank you sir. You are amazing. I was debugging for 4 hours and didn't realize this stupid mistake of mine until I read your answer!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I accidentally assigned the same name to both a class method and an imported trait resulting in a loop of $this->doThis() -->  $this->doThis() -->  $this->doThis() -->  $this->doThis()...

Answer (score 2):

I had this when calling

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->toArray()
```

on an `User` model that has a relation to `Address` model, when the `Address` model has a relation to the same `User` model... it was a loop.

It was a loop that has broken - `toArray()`

The error I got on my Laravel 5.7 was:

> Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached, aborting!

**Solution**

go to Address model and add the protected attribute

```
protected $hidden = ['user']; // for toArray
```

Comment: Well the error came up when I was using `laravel-5.2` but thank you so much I will keep in mind the solution in my future projects. I appreciate

Comment: This problem ans solution would be the same for Laravel 5.2, even though I did not test it on all the versions of Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

I had a Global Scope on my User Model that used Auth::check(),  causing a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the line

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 120);
```

in the file bootstrap/autoload.php in the Laravel 5.2

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error here:
`xdebug.max_nesting_level` is set to `500`

```
$guards = array_keys(config('auth.guards'));
$this->authenticate($request, $guards);
```